# Rotating a 3D figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, geometry-surface

I generated a 3D surface in matlab.

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

x = [1:0.1:5];
y=[1:50];  
[n1 n2] = size(x);
[m1, m2] = size(y);

for i = 1 : m2
    for j = 1 : n2

        z(i,j) = (x(1,j)) / (y(1,i));           
    end
end
[x, y] = meshgrid(x, y);

surf(y, x, z)
colorbar
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
```

I got the following plotted surface:

[image]

**I am interested now to rotate the cube of a quarter turn in the clockwise direction**. I know that I can use the "`rotate3d on`" and choose the best *Az* and *EI*, but I didn't understand what are *Az* and *EI* and how should be equal to respond to my need?

For example:

[image]

There also another function called `camroll()`. But I don't know what must the value in () in order to rotate the cube of a quarter turn in the clockwise direction. Does 90 degree is the correct answer?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Why dont you make a simple test? rotate by an angle you know how it should behave and than extrapolate this to the one you need.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer:), I just want to rotate the cube of a quarter turn in the clockwise direction. But how to choose Az and AI when using "rotate3d".

Comment: check the rotate function of matlab. you have 3 directions so in a way you have 3 clockwise directions. if you want to rotate in x axis by 45 degrees you would make rotate(h,[1,0,0],45). hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @ASantosRibeiro mentioned, the rotate function will produce the output you want. As an aside, here is a vectorized version of your code, which you might find useful if you have a significantly larger data set.

```
x = 1:0.1:5;
y=1:50;  

X = repmat(x',1,size(y,2)).';
Y = repmat(y',1,size(x,2));
Z = X./Y;

figure
hSurf = surf(Y,X,Z);

rotate(hSurf,[1,0,0],45) % As proposed by @ASantosRibeiro

colorbar
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
```

The [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) function is used to replicate both x and y in order to form X and Y with correct sizes to be allowed to divide one by the other in order to form Z. This operation is quite similar to the call to meshgrid in your code. For a small dataset like the one in your example the running times are similar with both methods (on my laptop), however when I use x = 1:0.1:500 and y = 1:500 for example the vectorized version takes 3x less time, so it might be worthwhile to look at it.

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Careful though. The `rotate` function will rotate the _object_, not the view (camera angle). It means all the data points will actually change coordinates. It is not a problem if the final use is only for this visualization, but it will have consequences if you plan on retrieving the coordinates of your object later on. Otherwise, good job for the `repmat` pointer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To rotate the figure axis you can use the **view** command:

```
surf(rand(20))
for az = 360:-1:-0
    view(az, 30)
    pause(0.01)
end
```

Azimus has values in between 0° and 360°. To turn the axis figure by 90° in counter-clockwise direction you oculd choose the azimuths of: [270, 180, 90, 0]